# Firestore StreamProvider does not update state with Auth changes

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

I have a function that returns a `Stream<List<Ticket>>` where Ticket is a model. `_user` is a `FriebaseAuthUser`.

```dart
Stream<List<Ticket>> userTickets() {
  if (_user == null || _user.isAnonymous) return Stream<List<Ticket>>.empty();
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("support-tickets/${_user.uid}/tickets")
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .map(
        (QuerySnapshot snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map(
          // populate model
        ).toList(),
      );
}
```

I am using this provider:

```dart
StreamProvider<List<Ticket>>.value(
  value: _dataApi.userTickets(),
  builder: // build MaterialApp
)
```

I am using the list inside the app with:
`Provider.of<List<Ticket>>(context);`

When I sign in the list gets populated from Firestore. When I sign out or sign in as anonymous user the list does not change even though I am returning an empty stream.

Tracing the code I can see that _user is indeed either null or isAnonymous and the value returned from the function is an empty stream, but this does not cause state change of the list populated earlier when signed in.

When I sign in with a different user the list gets populated with new values for that user.

Comment: I think you need to wrap StreamProvider in `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChages` stream, so whenever the auth state changes the StreamBuilder will be repainted.

Comment: It's already wrapped inside an authStateChanges provider

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by returning a single data event stream of an empty list if user is anonymous or null:
`if (_user == null || _user.isAnonymous) return Stream.value([]);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for leading me to solution.  This feels like a bug with StreamProvider which should handle Stream.empty().

Solution for single-value stream listeners, returning

```
Stream.value(null)
```

For Lists:

```
Stream.value([])
```

Instead of

```
Stream.empty()
```